# Change date format from 25-01-2012 to 25-JAN-2012 in asp gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

In an ASP Gridview table, one of the columns (Date) will display in the format 25-01-2012.

How can I change the format from `25-01-2012` to `25-JAN-2012` with a javascript function?
The Markup is

```
<asp:BoundColumn  DataField="MyDate"  HeaderText="Day&amp;" >    
<ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
```

Comment: I think you can do that with asp.net code too

Answer (score 1):

You can use asp.net code to change the date format

```
<asp:GridView runat="server">
<Columns>
   <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MyDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
in the grid the records are getting populated from two different tables.
i tried this but not working.
can we do this using javascript ?

Comment: You got downvoted probably because you did not show your code. Show your markkup

Comment: What happened when you tried this? It should work. Do you get an error? Do the dates not change? You mention the data comes from two tables, is DataReqFormat stored as DateTime? Is there any date time to string conversion happening before the databind? You are better off doing this server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MyDate" HeaderText="Day&amp;" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}">
<ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
```